# HttpResponse as string - turning numbers into letters

Tags: json, vb.net, integer, httpresponse

I am connecting to a web API and asking for a response but my response is being shown incorrectly like "high":4.166e-5 when i am expecting something like 0.00004166 as the figures I am asking for are market prices in BTC, I figure it is a 32bit integer issue but its a string so im lost. Sorry if I am not explaining this very well.

this is the response i am reading:

```
 `{"date":1493626200,"high":4.166e-5,"low":4.158e-5,"open":4.166e-5,"close":4.158e-5,"volume":0.05681982,"quoteVolume":1364.65936831,"weightedAverage":4.163e-5}]
```

this is how im formatting the httpresponse

```
`   Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync(privUrl, myContent).Result

        If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
            Dim json As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
            Return json
        End If
```

and then deserializing with this

```
        Dim json As String = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer).ToString()
```

EDIT***

Now im using EuX0 example and still getting an error
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'class_test.FormatOutputData' because the type requires a JSON object

```
Dim responseFromServer As String = apiSettings.TradingApi("returnTradeHistory&currencyPair=BTC_XRP")
TextBox1.AppendText(responseFromServer) 'so i can see whats coming in
Dim jsonString As String = responseFromServer
**Dim obj As FormatOutputData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FormatOutputData)(jsonString)**
obj.outputValues()
```

this is a the whole JSON output`[{"globalTradeID":116229026,"tradeID":"4728521","date":"2017-05-01 11:21:43","rate":"0.00004113","amount":"6118.34548991","total":"0.25164754","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40272934869","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116227160,"tradeID":"4728350","date":"2017-05-01 11:17:51","rate":"0.00004115","amount":"4.08198005","total":"0.00016797","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40271626179","type":"buy","category":"settlement"},{"globalTradeID":116227159,"tradeID":"4728349","date":"2017-05-01 11:17:51","rate":"0.00004115","amount":"998.42429344","total":"0.04108515","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40271625180","type":"buy","category":"marginTrade"},{"globalTradeID":116226661,"tradeID":"4728312","date":"2017-05-01 11:16:50","rate":"0.00004125","amount":"1000.00000000","total":"0.04125000","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40271087718","type":"sell","category":"marginTrade"},{"globalTradeID":116207504,"tradeID":"4726343","date":"2017-05-01 10:44:17","rate":"0.00004169","amount":"6046.78987712","total":"0.25209066","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40258966851","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165595,"tradeID":"4721962","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:29","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"5908.02441914","total":"0.24122463","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165589,"tradeID":"4721961","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:29","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"3.77406151","total":"0.00015409","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165569,"tradeID":"4721960","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:28","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"144.21964328","total":"0.00588848","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826811,"tradeID":"4679609","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"153.45158215","total":"0.00584650","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826810,"tradeID":"4679608","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"262.48126299","total":"0.01000053","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826809,"tradeID":"4679607","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"5253.48043078","total":"0.20015760","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826808,"tradeID":"4679606","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"836.80554752","total":"0.03188229","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"}]jsonString: [{"globalTradeID":116229026,"tradeID":"4728521","date":"2017-05-01 11:21:43","rate":"0.00004113","amount":"6118.34548991","total":"0.25164754","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40272934869","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116227160,"tradeID":"4728350","date":"2017-05-01 11:17:51","rate":"0.00004115","amount":"4.08198005","total":"0.00016797","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40271626179","type":"buy","category":"settlement"},{"globalTradeID":116227159,"tradeID":"4728349","date":"2017-05-01 11:17:51","rate":"0.00004115","amount":"998.42429344","total":"0.04108515","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40271625180","type":"buy","category":"marginTrade"},{"globalTradeID":116226661,"tradeID":"4728312","date":"2017-05-01 11:16:50","rate":"0.00004125","amount":"1000.00000000","total":"0.04125000","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40271087718","type":"sell","category":"marginTrade"},{"globalTradeID":116207504,"tradeID":"4726343","date":"2017-05-01 10:44:17","rate":"0.00004169","amount":"6046.78987712","total":"0.25209066","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40258966851","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165595,"tradeID":"4721962","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:29","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"5908.02441914","total":"0.24122463","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165589,"tradeID":"4721961","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:29","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"3.77406151","total":"0.00015409","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165569,"tradeID":"4721960","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:28","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"144.21964328","total":"0.00588848","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826811,"tradeID":"4679609","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"153.45158215","total":"0.00584650","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826810,"tradeID":"4679608","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"262.48126299","total":"0.01000053","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826809,"tradeID":"4679607","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"5253.48043078","total":"0.20015760","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826808,"tradeID":"4679606","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"836.80554752","total":"0.03188229","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"}]`

Comment: The first problem is that your JSON string is incomplete. It should end in "]" not a comma. So if you could provide the full string that would be great. Also your example JSON string contains more than one of the FormatOutPutData object so you need to do something like:


    Dim obj() as FormatOutPutData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FormatOutputData())(jsonString)

And then display it like: obj(x).outputValues()

Comment: I have updated the json, the output I have now with your example is Global TradeID: 116226661
TradeID: 4728312
High: 0
Low: 0
Open: 0
Close: 0
Volume: 0
QuoteVolume: 0
WeightedAverage: 0,     but these are missing the info

Comment: Your json string is still messed up I believe there shouldn't be "jsonString:" in the middle of it. Also the info is not there because your json string only contains globalTradeID, tradeID, date, rate, amount, total, fee, ordernumber, type and category.

Check out my original answer for updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
       Dim jsonString As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\1.txt")
       Console.WriteLine(String.Format("jsonString: {0}{1}", jsonString, vbNewLine))
       Dim objarray As New List(Of FormatOutputData)
       objarray.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FormatOutputData())(jsonString))
       For Each item As FormatOutputData In objarray
           item.outputValues()
       Next
       Console.ReadLine()
   End Sub


Private Class FormatOutputData
    Public globalTradeID As Long
    Public tradeID As Long
    Public [date] As String
    Public rate As Decimal
    Public amount As Decimal
    Public total As Decimal
    Public fee As Decimal
    Public orderNumber As String
    Public type As String
    Public category As String

    Public Sub outputValues()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("globalTradeID: {1}{0}tradeID: {2}{0}date: {3}{0}rate: {4}{0}amount: {5}{0}total: {6}{0}fee: {7}{0}orderNumber: {8}{0}type: {9}{0}category: {10}{0}",
                                        vbNewLine, globalTradeID, tradeID, [date], rate, amount, total, fee, orderNumber, type, category))
    End Sub
End Class
End Module
```

Example of output:

```
jsonString: [{"globalTradeID":116229026,"tradeID":"4728521","date":"2017-05-01 11:21:43","rate":"0.00004113","amount":"6118.34548991","total":"0.25164754","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40272934869","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116227160,"tradeID":"4728350","date":"2017-05-01 11:17:51","rate":"0.00004115","amount":"4.08198005","total":"0.00016797","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40271626179","type":"buy","category":"settlement"},{"globalTradeID":116227159,"tradeID":"4728349","date":"2017-05-01 11:17:51","rate":"0.00004115","amount":"998.42429344","total":"0.04108515","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40271625180","type":"buy","category":"marginTrade"},{"globalTradeID":116226661,"tradeID":"4728312","date":"2017-05-01 11:16:50","rate":"0.00004125","amount":"1000.00000000","total":"0.04125000","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40271087718","type":"sell","category":"marginTrade"},{"globalTradeID":116207504,"tradeID":"4726343","date":"2017-05-01 10:44:17","rate":"0.00004169","amount":"6046.78987712","total":"0.25209066","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40258966851","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165595,"tradeID":"4721962","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:29","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"5908.02441914","total":"0.24122463","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165589,"tradeID":"4721961","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:29","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"3.77406151","total":"0.00015409","fee":"0.00150000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":116165569,"tradeID":"4721960","date":"2017-05-01 09:19:28","rate":"0.00004083","amount":"144.21964328","total":"0.00588848","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40228860987","type":"buy","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826811,"tradeID":"4679609","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"153.45158215","total":"0.00584650","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826810,"tradeID":"4679608","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"262.48126299","total":"0.01000053","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826809,"tradeID":"4679607","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"5253.48043078","total":"0.20015760","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"},{"globalTradeID":115826808,"tradeID":"4679606","date":"2017-04-30 23:10:36","rate":"0.00003810","amount":"836.80554752","total":"0.03188229","fee":"0.00250000","orderNumber":"40019069988","type":"sell","category":"exchange"}]

globalTradeID: 116229026
tradeID: 4728521
date: 2017-05-01 11:21:43
rate: 0,00004113
amount: 6118,34548991
total: 0,25164754
fee: 0,00150000
orderNumber: 40272934869
type: buy
category: exchange

globalTradeID: 116227160
tradeID: 4728350
date: 2017-05-01 11:17:51
rate: 0,00004115
amount: 4,08198005
total: 0,00016797
fee: 0,00250000
orderNumber: 40271626179
type: buy
category: settlement
```

EDIT2:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim nestedJsonClass As NestedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of NestedJson)(jsonString)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Order number: {0}", nestedJsonClass.orderNumber))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("   ->:amount: {0}", nestedJsonClass.resultingTrades.Item(0).amount))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("   ->:date: {0}", nestedJsonClass.resultingTrades.Item(0).Date))

End Sub

Private Class NestedJson
    Public orderNumber As ULong
    Public resultingTrades As New List(Of Nested)
End Class

Private Class Nested
    Public amount As Decimal
    Public [Date] As String
    Public rate As Decimal
    Public total As Decimal
    Public tradeID As Long
    Public type As String
End Class
```

EDIT3:

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim jsonInput As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\1.txt")
    Dim whatEver As topLevelObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of topLevelObject)(jsonInput)
    Console.WriteLine(whatEver.asks(0)(0))
    Console.WriteLine(whatEver.asks(0)(1))
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Class topLevelObject
    Public asks() As List(Of Object)
    Public bids() As List(Of Object)
    Public isFrozen As String
    Public seq As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your time EuX0, I know what I need now, just one question, why was the numbers coming back like 4.166e-5 originally? What makes numbers convert to letters?

Comment: If it was coming like that from the server then I am afraid I don't know. One possibility is that sending 4.166e-5 instead of 0.00004166 over millions of requests saves you some bandwidth but this is purely speculation.

Edit: For what converts numbers to letters it's called e-notation.

Comment: if i may ask one more question :/  how aslo deal with a nested response like this  {"orderNumber":31226040,"resultingTrades":[{"amount":"338.8732","date":"2014-10-18 23:03:21","rate":"0.00000173","total":"0.00058625","tradeID":"16164","type":"buy"}]}

Comment: Hi again :/ I really struggle with these Json arrays, if the respose contains multiple arrays how can i deserialize something with more than one? eg  {"asks":[["0.00003845",9154.92874356],["0.00003847",226928.15354519],["0.00003848",44814.73762307],["0.00003849",66530.93415207],["0.00003850",602872.53278386]],"bids":[["0.00003844",234219.98409858],["0.00003843",3049.94204944],["0.00003841",630],["0.00003840",722.42637274],["0.00003839",2604.84501172]],"isFrozen":"0","seq":49010907}  I cant use JsonConvert.deserialize with with a response like this

Comment: Hey thanks so much, im starting to get the idea. I find it difficult to visualize how i can create and use these classes. Do you have any tips on how I can visualize them?

Comment: Use some kind of [JSON](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) [formatter.](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)